# How to insert a line break in a SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, ibatis

I have a `java` apps.

I insert some text into `sql server database`

***java:***

```
courriel.setTxtCouContenu(corps);
```

When i inspect my var `corps` i have this:

[image]

You can see `\r\n`

So when i look in my database there is not  line break.

My insert statement (iBatis):

```
<statement id="insert"
    parameterClass="test.business.bo.TestBO"
    resultClass="java.math.BigDecimal">
    INSERT INTO dbo.E_COUR (ID, CORPS,)
    VALUES (#testBO.id:Numeric#,
    #corps:Varchar#)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    AS value
</statement>
```

Comment: Where and how do you *look in your database*? If you use SSMS try to set the output to text. Grid data will never show line breaks... And be aware that the line breaks may differ in systems...

Comment: @Shnugo i look in my database with my java apps

Comment: If you are inserting text with proper line breaks the way you do it, it should work. How are you proofing, that the inserted text does not include the line breaks anymore?

Comment: @Shnugo in my app i send mail with the inserted text and when i see the maiil line breaks does not include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `\r\n` still in the string when you use the inserted content or will this vanish?

Try this in SSMS:

```
declare @tbl TABLE(testString VARCHAR(100));
insert into @tbl VALUES('test with \r\n encoded line break')
                      ,('test with' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'windows line break') 
                      ,('test with' + CHAR(10) + 'simple line break');
```

Now switch to (output to text (ctrl+T) )

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

The result:

```
test with \r\n encoded line break

test with
windows line break

test with
simple line break
```

With "output to datagrid (ctrl+D)" you will not see the line breaks anyway...